# Android DrawText not working on SurfaceView

Tags: java, android, eclipse, graphics

Working on adding Text to my canvas however the canvas.drawText(...) method is not working (NOT RENDERING ANYTHING ) despite other draw calls working perfectly fine. Case in point, I'm drawing lines/bitmaps on the canvas but drawing text keeps failing.

Order: MainActivity -> GameActivity -> GameThread:Thread -> GamePanel: SurfaceView

Code:
    public void render(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

```
    //draws the vector line!
    if(this.PAUSED == 2)
        this.drawLine(canvas);
    playerOne.render(canvas);
    for(int a=0; a < GameConstants.floatingStructures.size(); a++)
    {
        GameConstants.floatingStructures.get(a).render(canvas);//renders each item to the canvas
    }

    Paint textPaint =  new Paint(Color.RED);
    textPaint.setTextSize(16);
    textPaint.setStrokeWidth(30);
    textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    textPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
    canvas.drawText("HelloWorld", 0, 400,textPaint);
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

P.s. I've also tried it with this code:

```
    Paint textPaint =  new Paint(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawText("HelloWorld", 0, 400,textPaint);
```

Screenshot:
[image]

[image]

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you're as specific as you can be as to how the code is "not working".  Tell us what you expected and what you actually got.  As this relates to graphics, a screenshot may be helpful to explain exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Alright will post a screen shot, but to sum up text is not being rendered, everything else is. @JeffreyBosboom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter in the `Paint` constructor you're using - namely `Paint(int)` - is for flags, such as `ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG`, not color values. Change your instantiation and initialization as follows:

```
Paint textPaint = new Paint();
textPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: Omg, i can't believe i missed this, i'm dumb =_=

. THANKS!